# matplotlib plotting figsave issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, scaling, figure

Yesterday I came across something I want to understand in more detail:
The following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':

    plt.ion()
    fig = plt.figure()
    image_comb = np.random.random((300,50,4))
    plt.imshow(image_comb)

    plt.plot([0,50],[0,300], lw=20, color = 'red', alpha=0.3)
    plt.xlim(0,50)
    plt.ylim(0,300)
    plt.axis('off')

    [ax] = fig.get_axes()
    extent = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
    plt.savefig('test_fig.png', bbox_inches = extent)
    plt.close(fig)
```

launched via ipython within pycharm line by line produces this png file:

[image: launched line by line]

while the very same code launched via magic command %run ... again ipython within pycharm returns this png file:

[image: launched via magic %run command]

I have already understood, that what I get is my "picture" scaled to the standard dimension of a figure without figsize. I furthermore know, that it is possible to solve the issue by replacing plt.figure() by something like plt.figure(figsize=(0.5,3), dpi=100) but I am still wondering why both ways of launching differ in the first place. So what does exactly happen during  the launch with the magic %run command that causes the transformation?